# Couldn't find any way of displaying a message box in Visual Webpart 2007 (User Control)

Tags: 2007, development, visual-web-part, user-controls, messagebox

I almost tried everything I could to display a nice message box in user control (.ascx) or code behind, but I failed miserably,

Can anyone find me a tutorial in context to what I need and will 100% work please ?

Until now I tried Ajax Modal Popup and JavaScript but it breaks my "visual" webpart without any error, also if you can explain how can I use your suggested tutorial.

.ascx file

```
<%@ Assembly Name="Uk9999.Webparts.MyWebPart, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=678d049e0f7e2b28" %>
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="MyWebPartUserControl.ascx.cs"
    Inherits="UK9999.Webparts.MyWebPart.MyWebPartUserControl" %>
<%@ Register Assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
    Namespace="System.Web.UI" TagPrefix="asp" %>
<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="ajaxToolkit" %>
<div class="MainTable" style="font-family: calibri, verdana, sans serif">
    <div style="width: 100%">
        <div style="float: left; width: 45%; ">
```

There's more controls and then one update panel which is working fine.

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
                <ContentTemplate>
                    <div align="center" style="color:#*****">
                        <asp:Label ID="lbl1" ....
```

then in webpart class I am doing this

```
  public class MyWebpartClass: BaseWebPart
    {
        private const string _ascxPath = @"~/_ControlTemplates/MyWebpartClass/MyWebpartClassUserControl.ascx";

        private UserControl control;
        private ImageButton imagebutton;
        private Button btn;

        protected override void CreateChildControls()
        {
            try
            {
                base.CreateChildControls();

                control = (UserControl)Page.LoadControl(_ascxPath);
                Controls.Add(control);

                btn = (Button)this.control.FindControl("btnCalculate");
                imagebutton= (ImageButton)this.control.FindControl("btnSendEmail");


                btn.Click += new EventHandler(btn_Click);
```

Now in

```
protected void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {// I want to display a message box at the moment its using this.Page.Unload += event for displaying a div which does work but does a page refresh..}
```

**I changed controls names so dont get confused because of that**

Now also if I try to add JavaScript in it before first div e.g.

```
<script runat="server">
   void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
      Button1.Attributes.Add("onclick",
           "javascript:alert('ALERT ALERT!!!')");
   }
</script>
```

it displays a blank screen, no errors at all. same thing happens when I try this [Ajax Modal Popup](http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/ModalPopup/ModalPopup.aspx). I also tried different other tutorials but non of them actually works.

Comment: If you want to email the code to my email on profile I can take a look for you, see what you are trying to do, and make a proper suggestion. It all really depends how and when you want the popup. Would love to help.

Comment: @HughWood would love to do that, but because of company policy I can't pass this code to anyone, however its simply too large to change IDs name and that otherwise I would, however I try to add few bits in my question

Comment: What do you want the popup to do and say? You could bind a javascript function to the button client side, and do it that way, I can do an example of that if it's suitable.

Comment: Just a message box, I already tried what your saying but then My webparts shows nothing but blank screen without any errors.

Comment: Can you create a JSFiddle showing how you adding the popup? Then we can work on it. Maybe copy some of the html involved, and recreate a simpler version there? I finish here in about an hour but I can be on all evening GMT time. JSfiddle.net

Comment: Use Prop instead of attributes.add, it works cross browser. This might be the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a update panel and added my control in it, then using JavaScript I am catching end request of update panel and then displaying a message box, I have been looking for this solution since ages.

```
 <script type="text/javascript"> 
   // if you use jQuery, you can load them when dom is read.
   $(document).ready(function () {
       var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();    
       prm.add_initializeRequest(InitializeRequest);
       prm.add_endRequest(EndRequest);

    });        

    function InitializeRequest(sender, args) {
    }

    function EndRequest(sender, args) 
    {
```

now you can display a message box or any other thing you want to do.

Hope it helps :) as I couldn't find any related post or tutorial on internet even after 7 days of search.

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you use OnClientClick property of Button? See this [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.onclientclick.aspx) for more information, and also you can use js as you want in ascx